# Laravel repository Class App\Repository\User does not exist

Tags: laravel

Hello I want to use my own repository class in my Laravel 5.8 project
I created my file Repository in the App File and in this file I added A class called ConversationRepository
This is my class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

class ConversationRepository{

    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user){

        $this->user=$user;
    }

    public function getConversation(int $userId){
       return  $this->user->newQuery()
       ->select('name','id')
       ->where('id','!=',$userId)
       ->get();
    }
}
```

And then when I use it on my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repository\ConversationRepository;



class ConversationsController extends Controller
{       
    private $r;
    private $auth;

    public function __construct(ConversationRepository $conversationRepository,AuthManager $auth){
        $this->r = $conversationRepository;
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function index(){


        return view('conversation.index',[
            'users'=>$this->r->getConversation($this->auth->user()->id)
        ]);

    }
    public function show(User $user){

        return view('conversation.show',['users'=>$this->r->getConversation(
            $this->auth->user()->id),
             'user'=>$user
             ]);
    }

    public function store(User $user){

    }
}
```

I get the error

```
Class App\Repository\User does not exist
```

Comment: try `public function __construct(App\User $user)` in the repo

Comment: It didn't work I tryed to put use App\User instead and  I get Class App\Http\Controllers\AuthManager does not exist it's seems like it's related

Comment: yes, something related to namespaces. Do you try adding `use App\Http\Controllers\AuthManager`?

Comment: I tryed it it's not working :(

Comment: Why is your repository and method called `ConversationRepository::getConversation()` when you return a list of `Users`? The naming is pretty bad all the way through, to be honest with you.

Comment: @Namoshek im not returning a list of users only but also a list of their conversations

Comment: Above repository code doesn't. And even if you did, the primary return type would still be a list of users which doesn't fit a conversation repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you forgot to add `use App\User;` in the `class ConversationsController` file.

Comment: I did in the controller do you mean in my class?

Comment: Exactly, or you could also try the solution of the comment of your question. Both work as well. It's just a matter of preference :)

Comment: I did it  and I think it's working but I get the error "Class App\Http\Controllers\AuthManager does not exist"

Comment: Awesome. One error less... It's the same mistake as with your initial question. You have to import your AuthManager class inside your controller. Basically something like use App\xxxxx\xxxxxxx\AuthManger; should do the job... let's get it working... (an upvote would be helpful for me)

Comment: I tryed to add the class but it's not working Im following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMGQAIIMne4&fbclid=IwAR3KZj89psLf_3ObdIu5GL6kWZYa_TMfOti6APGKgYqpzXI9PrMFPD-b2Wk min 25

Comment: Can you show me what's under your Auth\Http\Controllers\Auth folder?

Comment: when I open it I have just the default files the Auth controllers (in my project) ForgotPasswordController.php LoginController.php RegisterController.php ResetPasswordController.php VerificationController.php

Comment: At minute 23:02 he imports the class that you forgot. Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager...

Comment: Man, god bless you I need to sleep for real I didn't even notice thank you so much time for a break after 14 houres thank you

Comment: Just add use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager; to your the controller.

Comment: I'm always glad to help. Remember that rests are also part of work :) Feel free to contact me if you need help in further steps... Goodnight